# Bash communicating with executed binary. How?

Tags: bash

I'm running a binary inside the bash script like to communicate with it... (the binary uses stdin, stdout)

```
#!/bin/bash
touch kacsa.txt
echo `./bbox 2`>>kacsa.txt
echo 2
echo 2
read -r KACSA >> kacsa.txt
```

I want to run bbox with option 2 and then give a simple input (2,2) after that reading in what was the output, and putting it in a text file (kacsa.txt) please help

example: I can run bbbox like this

```
>>./bbox 2   //it runs now
2          // it was written by
2          //it was written by me
4            // bbx write in console
I want to do the same thing with bash... the outup should goes tho an text file "kacsa.txt"
```

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to do in a different way? I have problem understanding it

Comment: I can run bbbox like this
>>./bbox 2   //it runs know
2          // it was written by
2          //it was written by me
4            // bbx write in console
I want to do the same thing with bash... the outup shuold goes tho an text file "kacsa.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch kacsa.txt
(echo 2 ; echo 2) | ./bbox 2 >> kacsa.txt
```

stdin of `./bbox` is fed by the pipe.

stdout of `./bbox` is put in the file.

Comment: ok, but what if i want to this in loop... (with  executing binary)?
If i put this in a loop it will run  the binary then stop.. again and again.

Comment: Is there a problem with running/stopping the executable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to use `mkfifo`:

```
mkfifo passthrough.fifo
```

- process 1

  ```
  for a in 1 2 3 4 5; 
  do 
      echo hello world $a; 
      sleep 1; 
  done >> passthrough.fifo &
  ```
- process 2

  ```
  while read greeting target number < passthrough.fifo
  do
       echo received a greeting directed at "$target" saying: "'$hello'" (the number is $number)
  done
  ```

Either process (or both) could be a binary instead, of course

#### Co-procedures

Or look at **[bash 4+ coproc](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)**